# How to write the code in selenium webdriver but asking for user input first

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a table in a webpage and some ids get created which are hyperlinks and I want selenium webdriver to ask me for input as the input which is a hyperlink keeps on changing

```
Table IN WEBPAGE
 Header     Name    
  8277      tEST     
   23       YT
    1       Y
    23      55
```

The numbers under header are hyper links which keeps on changing and i want selenium to ask me for input. xpath for  headers are given below

```
xpath = //*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_cph_base_cph_pgf_cph_ctl00_gvLastPricings_ctl03_lbPricingDetails"]

//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_cph_base_cph_pgf_cph_ctl00_gvLastPricings_ctl04_lbPricingDetails"]

//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_cph_base_cph_pgf_cph_ctl00_gvLastPricings_ctl05_lbPricingDetails"]

//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_cph_base_cph_pgf_cph_ctl00_gvLastPricings_ctl06_lbPricingDetails"]
```

How to do the above

Comment: Can you please share the HTML source and also tell us which coding language you are using?

Comment: I need to automate the prompt using selenium webdriver

Comment: `Selenium` can't ask you for input, there are other ways to do it. But if your automated script waits for user input, its not really automated is it?

Comment: Yes , i need that only so that i can enter my input. how to do that

Comment: @unix_user what programming language?

Comment: its selenium using java

Comment: Selenium can't ask for input. you can do that in JAVA
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      String header= sc.nextLine();

But please note that you need to enter the value in console window and you can achieve this only when you are executing in some editor like eclipse.

Instead it is good practice to iterate through the web elements and get the header values. Share your HTML to investigate more on this

Comment: Instead of letting Selenium ask you for input (see other comments. not automated, not a Selenium feature) you should use a configurable approach. Either use command line arguments or properties for your testing environment and configure it as needed prior to test launch.